# If/then in regexp

Tags: php, regex

Condition:
If there is a digit at the beginning of the line, get one letter from the end of the line.

Pattern scheme:

```
(?(IF)THEN)
```

Implementation: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b2ea5d6112e546de704528add3c6f3f5f20a0af4

```
$a = '645 sdfjh';
preg_match("/(?(^[0-9])[a-z]$)/", $a, $var);
var_dump($var);
```

Error:
Compilation failed: assertion expected after (?( at offset 3 in...

Comment: The correct way to say that is really *"match something with a digit at the start and a letter at the end"*, and the entire expression either matches or it doesn't. There's no if-else in regex per se.

Comment: This ain't enough `echo is_numeric($str[0]) ? $str[-1] : null;`?

Comment: @deceze there are no such constructs in regular expressions (the CS kind, which we're not talking about here on SO), but there are in PCRE: see https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html#SEC21 and https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html

Comment: Actually, we are fortunate. PHP PCRE supports it. @BartKiers

Comment: @revo but how i can do it? ))

Comment: You are almost near: [`/^(?(?=\d).*\K[a-z]$)/`](https://regex101.com/r/pBGmRr/1) @fosh4455

Comment: @fosh4455 it's safer to use some less exotic syntax.

Comment: OP's problem is with the way he defined *condition* not the construct itself. @BartKiers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP PCRE has been supporting conditional subpatterns from its very early implementations. The major issue with your way of constructing it is [*condition [PCRE.ORG]*](https://pcre.org/pcre.txt):

> There  are  four  kinds of condition: references to subpatterns,
>   references to recursion, a pseudo-condition called DEFINE, and
>   assertions.

So changing it to a positive lookahead assertion and inserting `.*` for moving to the end of input string will make it work:

```
^(?(?=\d).*\K[a-z]$)
```

[PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/dWDs8)

Comment: Thank you what does mean `\K`?

Comment: `\K` is not on this page http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php

Comment: `\K` is a match resetter. If you try to remove it you'll see how result change. The page you should look at is http://de2.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php

Answer (score 0):

seems `IF` must be a zero-width assertion

```
(?(?=[0-9]).*([a-z]$))
```

[link updated](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b2ea5d6112e546de704528add3c6f3f5f20a0af4)

Comment: You should prepend your regex with `^`

Comment: But how does it work? It's just looking ahead. There is no pointer to the beginning of the line, but if I put a space before the first digit, then everything does not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $a = '645 sdfjh';
  if (preg_match("/^\d.*([a-z])$/", $a, $var)) {
    var_dump($var[1]);   # => "h"
  }

  $a = 'x645 sdfjh';
  if (preg_match("/^\d.*([a-z])$/", $a, $var)) {
    var_dump($var[1]);   # => won't be executed
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
<?php
$a = '645 sdfjh';

if(preg_match("/^[0-9]/", $a)){

var_dump(substr($a, -1));    

}
```

hope this help you .

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

You have problem in your pattern.

See below code. This will help you.

This will work fine.

```
$a = '645 sdfjh';
preg_match('/[^a-z_\-0-9]/i', $a, $var);
if($var == true)
{
    echo substr($a, -1);
}else
{
    echo 'not matched';
}
```